# UI Field Access Certification Question

Tags: record-type, dev401

Was wondering if I can get some veteran developers to weigh-in on the answer to this question:

A user can only see the fields A, B, and C on a record of Object X until the Stage field value on the record changes from New to working. Once the Stage held value is updated to Working and the record is saved, the user should be able to see fields A, B, C and D. 
How would an application developer configure this?

1. Use multiple Visualforce pages
2. Use workflow to change the field-level security
3. Use workflow to change the record type
4. Use validation rules to expose the field

I have tested it in Salesforce and I believe the answer should be 3. Using workflow to change the record type when the Stage held value is changed to "Working", but some of the practice exams are saying it is 1. Use multiple Visualforce pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I plan to take the DEV 401 exam soon, only have the ADM 201 certification right now. Thanks!

Comment: 1 is programmatic way and 3 is declarative way of doing that. Could be either of those depending on the use case, and the answer can be both 1 & 3 I believe - keep in mind it's multiple choice!

Comment: I just read the question again "How would an application developer configure this?" meaning that it points to configuration, in which case it's 3.

Comment: Multiple VF pages would hardly be optimal (#1) as the `rendered=` attribute on a single VF page could handle the conditional visibility based on Stage; #3 is useful as you can configure different page layouts based on recordtype so no coding is required.

Comment: Mark, I've changed the title of this question from "dev401 question" to something that fits the topic of the question. Remember you would hope for someone to find this question based on the topic they are seeking information about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both #1 and #3 are essentially correct, #1 being the programmatic way of achieving that and #3 declarative. Paying attention to this part of the question

> How would an application developer **configure** this?

I believe it's seeking for a declarative way of doing it so, meaning that the correct answer will be #3. However, the exam itself it's multiple choice which means most of the time there is more than 1 correct answer.